# Simple WPF App Splash Screen "Jumps" at startup

Tags: wpf, prism, splash-screen

My WPF app shows a PNG image as a splash screen at startup using the standard [MS recommended method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-wpf-application).  That is, I chose an existing image file and set its build action to "Splash Screen"  I like this because it's simple. No code to write, just a property.

But it's got a problem: It "jumps".

When my app is starting and the splash screen first appears it is large and centered on the screen as I want.  But then, almost immediately, it jumps up to the left and gets smaller.  As if its window goes from being maximized to only taking up part of the screen.

This "jump" happens even before the constructor of my Application object is reached so certainly long before my MainWindow is in mix.   And I'm certainly not resizing anything.

So what could be causing this?  I can't even see that I can set a breakpoint anywhere to detect this.  Is there some property I can set somewhere to prevent this from happening?  Like maybe in my App.xaml?

I should say that this is a Prism 7.2 application using .NET core 3.1, if any of that matters

Answer (score 3):

If you override the:

```
protected virtual void OnStartup (System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e);
```

what you probably already do. Then you can control the splash screen a little bit more in there by:

```
SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen(YourImageFileName);
splashScreen.Show(false, true); // Auto-close: NO, On top: YES
```

And then later when you main window is ready to be shown, then:

```
splashScreen.Close(FadeTimeout); // FadeTimeout is of type TimeSpan
```

I know you liked the way, where you do not have anything in your code on the splash screen, but this little extra code you can control the splash screen much more. And it is probably what you need

Comment: Thank you for the reply.   I do plan to try this if I must.  I admit I'm a little concerned by the fact that the SplashScreen class doesn't seem to have any way to ensure that it gets maximized.  But I will cross that bridge when I come to it.  Still if anyone has any idea why this might be happening and how I might work around it without this code step, I would like to hear about it

Comment: If you apply your code, then it will be possible to figure out what is going on. I have tried to make a very simple test application just with a single window and splashscreen without any code for the splashscreen. And the splashscreen is shown maximized and disappears when the mainwindow is shown. So I think your problem is located in the initializing of your application and main window

Comment: Normally I would agree with you but my splash screen does the jump even before my application object reaches its constructor - and long before my main window is constructed.  So I don't that either of those is the culprit

Comment: How i can center that?

Answer (score 2):

The cause is something to do with the System Display "Scale" which you can adjust in the Settings panel:
[image: System Display Settings]

On my system, when scale is set to 100%, the problem disappears. Set the Scale to anything else, and the splash screen jumps.

It seems to also depend on which flavor of .NET you use:
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/5070

Comment: I didn't realize this reply had been made.  Sure looks like the issue.  I don't have time to test right now but when I do, assuming it's the case, I'll come back here and mark this as the answer

Comment: This explains why this is happening, but it does not provide a solution.  (Of course nobody is going to change the scale of their display so that some application's splash-screen shows centered.)

Comment: The OP did not ask for a solution, merely an explanation as to why the symptom occurs. My solution may not be perfect, but it does address the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to display scale and DPI Awareness.

You can read more about DPI Awareness here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

To fix the problem just declare your application as using Per-Monitor (V2) DPI Awareness. You can read how to do that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process

Use the method involving application manifest file.

- In Visual Studio add new item to project - file "app.manifest" from template "Application Manifest File"
- In the added file uncomment or add section

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

- (also set a right name in `<assemblyIdentity>` element)
- Make sure you have `<ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>` in your .csproj file.

Root cause of the problem:

WPF forces the use of DPI Awareness mode programmatically when it starts, but SplashScreen shows off before WPF starts. So the SplashScreen's window is already created when WPF calls [SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiawarenesscontext), but changing DPI awareness programmatically after creating any windows is officially not supported.

SplashScreen works well when DPI awareness is set properly from the beginning.

Comment: I have tested this solution, and it works for me! Thank you, Sinus32.